# Como transformar em minúsculo um valor de uma struct?

Tags: c, array, string, ponteiro, struct

A função seguinte deveria transformar variáveis em minúsculo para depois compará-las. Já tentei converter antes, mas também *bugou*. Uso aritmética de ponteiros junto a variáveis de uma `struct`. Ponteiro aponta para a `struct`.

Como consertar o erro presente no seguinte trecho de código:

```
struct registro{ 
    char conta[50], senha[50], usuario[50];
}atual[1000], *ptr;

int verifica_usuario(int *ptr){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < *ptr; i++) {
        if(strcmp(tolower(atual[*ptr].usuario), tolower(atual[i].usuario)) == 0) {
                return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: "Uso aritmética de ponteiros" não, você não usa aritmética de ponteiros. Você usa um simples acesso posicional do vetor `atual`. E também passar `int *ptr` como argumento parece bem desnecessário para o uso que está sendo feito dele

Comment: Sim, sim. Meu objetivo segue essa convicção, quero que o programa classifique "NOME" ==  "nome", daí o tolower. o programa é recepciona uma entrada na qual pede um nome de usuario, porém esse nome não pode já estar registrado, mesmo que haja divergência entre maiúsculo e minúsculo.

Comment: [`tolower`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/tolower/) recebe um char e devolve um char, logo não fará sentido chamar para um `char[]` ou `char*`. `atual.usuario` é de que tipo ?

Comment: É do tipo char, também.

Comment: Coloque a definição da `struct` na pergunta, para que seja evidente a qualquer pessoa que queira responder

Comment: O que o Isac quis dizer é: como está o código da `struct` entre a palavra recervada `struct`, seu abre chaves `{` e seu respectivo fecha chaves `}` com todas as definições de campos e seus respectivos nomes

Comment: Como está a chamar a sua função no `main` ?

Comment: verific = verifica_conta(&v);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embora existam funções insensitivas, não faz parte do padrão. Para rodar em qualquer lugar crie sua própria função:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
 
int stricmp(char const *s1, char const *s2) {
   while (1) {
        int res = tolower(*s1) - tolower(*s2);
        if (res != 0 || !*s1) return res;
        s1++;
        s2++;
    }
}
 
int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", stricmp("aaa", "AAA"));
    printf("%d\n", stricmp("aaa", "aaa"));
    printf("%d\n", stricmp("aaa", "AAB"));
    printf("%d\n", stricmp("abb", "AAB"));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/6QVqHP). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/dasceiqn-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/stricmp.c).

Aí verificar o membro da estrutura acho que já sabe. Siga as recomendações dos comentários, o algoritmo está mais complicado do que deve. E tem outros erros nele, mas aí é outro problema.