# Função que converte string para minúsculo e compara

Tags: c, string, funções, struct

```
struct registro{ /*Estrutura para guardar os dados do usuário*/
char usuario[50]; }atual[1000], *ptr; 
main() {
int v = 0; verific = 0; //posicao e variavel para comp. de string
volta_usuario:
printf("\n\t\t\tUsuário: ");
gets(atual[v].usuario);
verific = verifica_usuario(&v);
    if(verific == 0) {
        printf("\t\t\tUsuário já existente");
        goto volta_usuario;
    } v++; goto volta_usuario;} int verifica_usuario(int *ptr){
int i;
int cmp1;
int cmp2;
for(i = -1; i < *ptr; i++) {
    cmp1 = tolower(atual[*ptr].usuario);
    cmp2 = tolower(atual[i + 1].usuario);
    if(strcmp(cmp1,cmp2) == 0){
        return 0;
    }
}
return 1;}
```

O código acima deveria pedir do usuário um nome, quando chamasse a função `verifica_usuario(&v);` o programa deveria converter a última `string` lida para minúsculo e, durate um laço, converter as outras strings (também para minúsculo) para depois comparar e ver se existem strings iguais. Meu objetivo é: se caso a pessoa digite "nome" e depois digitasse "NOME" ou "Nome" (etc) o programa deve reconhecer que esse usuário já existe, ou seja, não faz diferenciação entre maiúsculos e minúsculos .Já tentei de diversas maneiras corrigir o bug dessa função destacada, mas sem êxito. Gostaria de ajuda para resolver esse problema.

Comment: A `stricmp` da [resposta do Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/251887/64969) resolve seu problema de comparação mantendo o estado da string para posterior apresentação

Comment: Aproveitando, `goto`? Você está fazendo um laço da maneira errada. Tente fazer um fluxograma dos dados e então implemente o laço adequado. Veja mais nessa pergunta sobre o assunto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/251860/64969

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, poderia me guiar em como realizar esse código da maneira correta, me ajudando a como fazê-lo, pelo menos a função?

Comment: Você entendeu a resposta do Maniero?

Comment: Não entendi, não.

Comment: Então por que marcou a resposta dele como correta?

Comment: Sou novato aqui.

Comment: Faça o [tour], será de grande proveito

Comment: A, obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Sempre que não entender uma resposta procure solicitar esclarecimentos com o autor da mesma. Se não o fizer a pessoa que respondeu fica convencida que conseguiu ajudar quando não foi o caso. Isto também evita criar perguntas "repetidas" por não ter percebido as respostas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu fiz um programa há algum tempo em que a função é realizar a **conversão minúscula -> maiúscula** de cada letra do texto digitado pelo usuário. Veja o código:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void ){

    char str1[30];
    int  tam,i;

    printf( "TEXTO:\n" );
    gets( str1 );

    tam = strlen( str1 );

    for( i = 0; i <= tam; i++ ){

        if( ( str1[i] >= 65 ) && ( str1[i] <= 90 ) )

            str1[i] = str1[i] + 32;

        else if( ( str1[i] >= 97 ) && ( str1[i] <= 132 ) )

            str1[i] = str1[i] - 32;

    }

    puts( str1 );

    getche();

}
```

Também já fiz um programa que **compara *strings***. Veja o código:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){

    char str1[20], str2[20], str3[20];
    int i, tam, tam2, comp;

    printf( "TEXTO:\n" );
    gets( str1 );

    printf( "TEXTO:\n" );
    gets( str2 );

    comp = strcmp( str1, str2 );

    if( comp == 0 ) printf("IGUAIS\n"); 
    else {

         strncat( str1, str2, 15 );
         printf( "DIFERENTES\nCONCATENADAS = %s\n", str1 );

    }

    getche();

}
```